# Joining SELECT of two rows with same id in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

ok I do have this table

```
| id | first | last | type
  1     mp      de    bill
  1     mark    ve    ship
  2     dw      her   bill
  2     dwi     rra   ship
```

now I want it to be like this

```
| id | bill.first |  bill.last | ship.first | ship.last
   1     mp             de           mark       ve
   2     dw             her          dwi        rra
```

the main key of joining rows is by their ID is this possible?

I tried already using group by but I don't have an idea how to use it

and I don't know what word to use in google to search for the solution to my problem

**I have only one table**

Comment: When you tried something, you should post it in your question ;)

Comment: Do you always have two records (ie a bill and a ship) and if not what should happen if you only have one or the other record?

Comment: I am trying but I failed :(

Comment: I do have always both the records of ship and bill it never miss out

Comment: Does the second table exist?

Comment: Just for the record this is a poor design for the table.

Comment: no second table exists

Comment: @Jake1164 its a magento table...

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work -

```
select 
    t1.first,
    t1.last,
    t2.first,
    t2.last,
    t1.type
    from 
    test t1
    inner join test t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
    and t1.type = 'bill'
    and t1.type != t2.type
```

Effectively, all you need is to perform an inner join on the same table

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `group by` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when type = 'bill' then first end) as "bill.first",
       max(case when type = 'bill' then last end) as "bill.last",
       max(case when type = 'ship' then first end) as "ship.first",
       max(case when type = 'ship' then last end) as "ship.last"
from table t
group by id;
```

For your case, this produces exactly the same results as the `join`.  However, if you have multiple rows for a given value, then this will still generate only one row per id.  Using `max()` it will give one value from one of the rows.  Using `group_concat()` it would give all the values.

One advantage of this approach is that it will include all ids, even when some ids are missing "bill" records and others are missing "ship" records.  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support `full outer join`, so that situation is more difficult to handle using `join`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
select bill.id, bill.first, bill.last, ship.first, ship.last
from t as bill, t as ship 
where bill.id = ship.id
and bill.type = 'bill' 
and ship.type = 'ship'
```

Or you could use a Join to be more contemporary.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.id, b.first, b.last, s.first, s.last 
FROM bill b
LEFT JOIN ship s ON b.id=s.id AND b.type='bill' AND s.type='ship'
```

Answer (score 0):

*try this:*

```
SELECT A.id,A.first, A.last,
       B.first, B.last
FROM   T2 A
INNER JOIN T2 B
ON A.id = B.id
AND A.type = 'bill'
AND B.type = 'ship'
```

Comment: there is no other table